# Modules in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
module Debug
  def whoAmI?
    "#{self.type.name} (\##{self.id}): #{self.to_s}"
  end
end

class Phonograph
  include Debug
  # ...
end

ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")
ph.whoAmI? # => "Phonograph (#537766170): West End Blues"
```

In `ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")`, why is the string `"West End Blues"` passed when there is no initialization method?

Does `self` refer to the current object? If so, wouldn't `self.to_s` return the instance of the object, e.g. `ph`?

Comment: Note that Ruby methods follow the `who_am_i` convention, avoiding capital letters. Same goes for variables.

Comment: Also this code does not work this way, so you must have something else going on here. When I try and reproduce that I get an error about `initialize` not supporting any arguments, which is expected.

Comment: `ph = Phonograph.new("West End Blues")` => **ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)**

Comment: I just copied it from a website, assumed that it worked